# Why does Microsoft identity need a local database

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, adfs, microsoft-identity-platform

I currently have a front-end website that is an ASP.NET Core Web App (MVC). I've added authorization and authentication using Microsoft Identity and ADFS for single sign on using OpenId Connect ([this](https://blog.matrixpost.net/set-up-active-directory-federation-services-ad-fs-5-0-claim-aware-web-applications-create-an-asp-net-core-web-app-model-view-controller-using-openid-connect-part-7/)). My question is, why does Microsoft Identity need a local DB with credentials for each user (from ADFS) and is it possible to avoid this?

The reason why I do not want this is, I'll exclusively be using the ADFS server for authentication and having this additional database would defeat the point of ADFS, centralized storage and centralized management. I understand in some scenarios its possibly better performing to store them locally when looking at SSO with Google or Microsoft but for smaller orgs is it possible to configure it to just use the ADFS server. Furthermore, if I wanted to create multiple web applications, this would mean I would have to create a server for this DB to run from, or each applications would need to implement its own database.

Please let me know if I am missing something, or can point me in the direction of useful resources.

Thanks, Adam

EDIT 1:

```
//services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        //    options.UseSqlite(
        //        Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        //services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
        //    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
        {
            HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
            handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator;
            options.BackchannelHttpHandler = handler;

            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.ClientId = "";
            options.Authority = "";
            options.SignedOutRedirectUri = "htpps://localhost:44397";
            options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents()
            {
                OnRemoteFailure = OnAuthenticationFailed
            };
        });

        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();

        services.AddAuthorization(opts =>
        {
            opts.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
        });
```

Comment: You don't need a local database.  I guess the majority of users will need a database, hence why all the examples and templates use one, but you can wire it up to call other services to handle the user lookup/claims retrieval.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Do you have any resource that can get me started on how to do this?

Comment: Have you tried just removing the identity configuration in startup.cs ?

Comment: I removed the code as shown in edit 1, but it get a schema error. 
InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found. The default schemes can be set using either AddAuthentication(string defaultScheme) or AddAuthentication(Action<AuthenticationOptions> configureOptions).

Comment: SQL Server requires the service and database (the MDF file) to be physically on the same machine.  I assume the ADFS also uses same rules.  Why would a database server need the file on a different machine?  As long as you can run the service remotely do you care where the file is actually loaded?

Comment: Hi Jdweng, I'm not really sure what you mean here

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why that sample uses Microsoft Identity and a DB. Totally unnecessary.

All you need to do is add an MSAL library to your app. e.g. [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/msal/adfs-msal-web-app-web-api).

The MSAL library handles OIDC for you.

MSAL libraries have support for a number of [scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-v2-libraries).

Comment: Thanks for the response! This looks like the right thing, but all the examples use .NET framework (I'm not sure how to configure that startup), and each of the relevant scenarios for .NET Core use Azure AD (Which isn't a possibility for me) .

Comment: I've just read that MSAL only supports direct connect to ADFS with versions 2019 and onward making it not suitable for my use case.

Comment: Correct. In that case, use the ADAL libraries.

Comment: But in theory, you could use any OIDC library.

Comment: Or failing that, use WS-Federation e,g, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/ws-federation?view=aspnetcore-6.0#use-ws-federation-without-aspnet-core-identity